# Clickhouse - add a new column with the default value being based off another column

Tags: database, clickhouse, alter

I have a table in Clickhouse, `table1`, with columns `A` and `B`.  I want to alter this table to have a new column `C`.  For the purpose of default values (future data will have a different approach) I want `C` to be filled in with data from `A`.

I know how to achieve this with a static default value, e.g. `0` but that is not what I'm trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DEFAULT](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/table/#create-default-values) may accept expression not only static value:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN C String DEFAULT A
```